# How to return a nested parent child collection - C#

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have the sample below code snippet. I want the method to return nested rows in a parent child relationship. For Example, i could have 3 teams E.G England, Brazil and Canada which should be the top level parent. Then under each team, i could have something like below.

**England**

1. Jonh
2. Ronney
3. Gerarld

**Brazil**

- Tom
- Neymar

  - List item 1
  - List item 2
- Alex

**Canada**

- Player 1
- Palyer 2

As you can, a specific palyer can also have child items under them. And Those Child items can aslo have sub-child items.

CURRENT PROBLEM

The problem i am having is that the below code only returns England with its child items fine. It completely does not return Brazil and Canada & i can't seem to figure out why.

```
 public static ObservableCollection<ClubsAndPlayers> GetData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ClubsAndPlayers> clubs = new ObservableCollection<ClubsAndPlayers>();
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)SessionApp.SessionManager.Session["dtMyTask"];
        ClubsAndPlayers parent = null;
        ClubsAndPlayers firstChild = null;
        ClubsAndPlayers secondChild = null;
        ClubsAndPlayers thirdChild = null;

        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(dt, null))
        {

            if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
                parent = new ClubsAndPlayers("No Player Available ", "", "", "", "", null);

            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string strTaskParentUID = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TaskParentUID"]).Trim();
                    string strTaskID = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TaskUID"]).Trim();
                    string strTaskName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TaskName"]);
                    string strTaskStartDate = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TaskStartDate"]);
                    string strTaskEndDate = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TaskEndDate"]);
                    int TaskOutlineLevel = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["TaskOutlineLevel"]);

                    if (i == 0 && TaskOutlineLevel == 1)
                    {
                        parent = new ClubsAndPlayers(strTaskName, strTaskID, strTaskStartDate, strTaskEndDate, strTaskParentUID, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (TaskOutlineLevel)
                        {
                            case 2:
                                firstChild = new ClubsAndPlayers(strTaskName, strTaskID, strTaskStartDate, strTaskEndDate, strTaskParentUID, parent);
                                if (parent.ID == strTaskParentUID)
                                {
                                    parent.Items.Add(firstChild);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                secondChild = new ClubsAndPlayers(strTaskName, strTaskID, strTaskStartDate, strTaskEndDate, strTaskParentUID, firstChild);

                                if (firstChild.ID == secondChild.ParentId)
                                {
                                    firstChild.Items.Add(secondChild);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                thirdChild = new ClubsAndPlayers(strTaskName, strTaskID, strTaskStartDate, strTaskEndDate, strTaskParentUID, secondChild);
                                if (secondChild.ID == thirdChild.ParentId)
                                {
                                    secondChild.Items.Add(thirdChild);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        clubs.Add(parent);
        return clubs;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure whether I am interpreting your code correctly, as even the string `England` does not appear in there, but could your problem be linked to the condition `i == 0` in your `if` statement?

Comment: I cannot see how the code you have included could even come close to achieving what you are trying to do. There seems to be some implied assumptions of order in the data but at the same time you are checking for equality on the node ids to the parent ids, doing nothing if they are not equal. To make sense of what is happening you would need to include a sample data set, in the specific order the data is returned. You might want to rethink the overall approach, the code posted looks very fragile.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, you are right about the condition 1==0. Removing that condition and moving the line clubs.Add(parent); right after parent = new ClubsAndPlayers(,,,,..) in that same condition solved the issue.